# Multiple tikz chain alignement

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-chains

I would like to display this result :

[image: Expected result]

This is my code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below, start chain=2 going right, start chain=3 going right]
        \node[on chain=1] (a) {a};
        \node[on chain=1] (b) {b};
        \node[on chain=1] (c) {c};


    \chainin (a);
        \node[on chain=2] (d) {d};
        \node[continue chain=going below,on chain=2] (e) {e};
        \node[on chain=2] (f) {f};


    \chainin (d);
        \node[on chain=3] (g) {g};
        \node[continue chain=going below,on chain=3] (h) {h};
        \node[on chain=3] (i) {i};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the result of the code :

[image: Bad result]

What is the correct way to code this please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always provide a small but complete document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) beginning with  `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, which we can test as it is. Please, help people who will be willing to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

One of possible solutions is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm,
  start chain = going right,
every node/.append style = {on chain}
                        ]
\node   (a) {a};
\node   (b) {b};
\node   (c) {c};

\node[below=of a] (d) {d};
\node   (e) {e};
\node   (f) {f};

\node[below=of d] (g) {g};
\node   (h) {h};
\node   (i) {i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```